# Is it possible to view docker-compose logs in the output window running in Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

docker-compose on Windows is not able to be run in interactive mode.

```
ERROR: Interactive mode is not yet supported on Windows.
Please pass the -d flag when using `docker-compose run`.
```

When running docker-compose in detached mode, little is displayed to the console, and the only logs displayed under docker-compose logs appear to be:

```
Attaching to
```

which obviously isn't very useful.

Is there a way of accessing these logs for transient containers?

I've seen that it's possible to change the docker-daemons logging to use a file (without the ability to select the log location). Following this as a solution I could log to the predefined log location, then execute a copy script to move the files to a mounted volume to be persisted before the container is torn down. This doesn't sound ideal.

The solution I've currently gone with (also not ideal) is to wrap the shell script parameter in a dynamically created proxy script which logs all output to the mounted volume.

```
tempFile=myproxy.sh

echo '#!/bin/bash' > $tempFile
echo 'do.the.thing.sh 2> /data/log.txt'>>$tempFile
echo 'echo finished >> /data/logs/log.txt' >> $tempFile
```

Which then I'd call

```
docker-compose run -d doTheThing $tempFile
```

instead of

```
docker-compose run -d doTheThing do.the.thing.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose logs doTheThing`